# Laptop hard drive making clicking sound

Tags: hard-drive, clicking-sound

I recently got in a road accident and my laptop fell (HP Pavilion p045TX, Win 10 and Ubuntu dual boot). I booted it up and it started showing the automatic repair screen. I booted it in Ubuntu and It started fine. I restarted it again and I got the "Hard Disk not detected error". After that it never detected the hard disk and only made clicking sounds.

Is there any hope of repairing it or recovering the data? Is there something wrong with the head? I guess if the platters were broken, It would have never booted in the first place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a separate computer you could plug the HDD into to use it as a secondary drive? I've recovered data from disks where the head of the disk is toast, so it always fails to boot. But by using it as a secondary drive in another computer, I was usually able to recover all of the data with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use another computer to create a **persistent** USB Live image. Boot your laptop with it and try to mount your hard drive and recover the data.

Check `lsblk` to see if it detects the hard drive or not. If you find problems to recover the data in it, connect the Live image to the internet and install [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). You can use it to recover data.

Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

I hope you are OK after you car accident.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: the hard drive is gone.

Good news: if the platters weren't spinning at the time of accident (unlikely), then they are in all likelihood intact, and so (almost certainly) is the data on them.

The problem is that the shock probably twisted the head cart, and now the internal firmware can't read the platters. As a consequence, it never reports "Drive ready" to the host controller, so your disk is not detected. Probably, the first time it was still somewhat working.

If it now boots only in Ubuntu and does not detect the HD in Windows, it probably means that the heads can no longer "extend" as far as the whole Windows partition. I find it really weird, but who knows. But what I think happened is that the first time it booted, the movement was enough to break it for good. There's probably nothing you could have done differently. It's probably not *too* broken, but it's almost surely out of a non-professional's "reach".

It follows that no *software* solution is ever going to help you - it would be like trying to find an app that can make a smartphone work without its battery. Software can help if you *can* get to the hard disk to "talk", and the problem is "just" that it spouts gibberish.

## Sure-fire solution

Go to a disk recovery service where they'll be able to disassemble the disk and put it in a recovery harness to read your data back. It will set you back a considerable amount (where I live it's around 60 USD per gigabyte, but it varies depending on the disk make and model - and the damage. You might also get lucky and get back everything for about two-three times the cost of a new hard disk).

## Alternative solutions (spoiler: no good ones. Sorry)

**BAD**: try giving the hard disk a couple of hard "spins", clockwise and counterclockwise, in case (see below) the heads are actually OK and need to disengage from whatever locking mechanism they've been captured by. On modern hard disks AFAIK there's no such mechanism, so this method will avail you nothing. If the hard disk clicks, instead of "buzzing", this means that the heads are already free to move, it's just that they aren't where they should.

**Also, very important**: repeated attempts might break something (e.g. dislodge a reading head from the cart) and lead to scratching of the platter surface. Once *that* happens, data recovery chances plummet, while recovery costs skyrocket.

**ALSO BAD**: trying to boot the hard disk after cooling it in a sealed plastic bag in a refrigerator, or conversely heating it in a non-microwave oven to no more than 50-60 degrees. There are stories of people swearing it worked. If the hard disk clicks, instead of "buzzing", this means that the heads are already free to move.

**VERY BAD**: On some disks (Seagate Momentus if memory serves), a kick in the right (well, actually *wrong*) direction will "lock" the heads in place. Possibly this is a safety measure, don't know. By *very* carefully opening the disk in the cleanest place you can imagine, and pushing with a toothpick, you may be able to disengage the head - or destroy the hard disk utterly.

**EVEN WORSE**: having an absolutely **identical** hard disk, but working, you may be able to replace the platters with all the good data on them and place them in the working hard disk. If you have the hands of a neurosurgeon and a clean operating theater, possibly you stand a 10% chance of having it working. Tolerances with modern equipment are so tight that I wouldn't dream of trying.

Most of the above methods you'll find on a Google search, and the reason why they *might* have worked *for someone*, *in the past*, is that in the old by and by hard disks were much simpler, much more primitive, and proportionally much sturdier. I myself have disassembled and reassembled a Seagate SST-225 drive (10, or was it 20, *megabytes*? - hey, it was *sixty* floppy disks' worth of data! I think it was 1988), and *it worked*.

But if you want a recommendation, I'd hire a professional service.